# How can I change the directory for the encrypted files?

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, aes-gcm

I have developed this C# System that authentically encrypts files using AES-GCM algorithm. However, I don't want the encrypted file to be in same folder as original folder. How can I change it? Below is the sniplet of my code and where exactly I need help.

```
  foreach (string inputFilePath in inputFilePaths)
            {
                // Proceed if file exists
                if (File.Exists(inputFilePath))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        // Encrypt
                        byte[] key = PasswordAsKey();
                        string[] encryptedFileContents = AesGcmFileEncryption.Encrypt(inputFilePath, key);

                        // Here is where I need clarification
                        string outputFilePath = inputFilePath;
                        outputFilePath += ".AEncrypt";
                        if (File.Exists(outputFilePath))
                        {
                            skippedBecauseFileExists = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            File.WriteAllLines(outputFilePath, encryptedFileContents);
                            counter++;

                            // Status
                            label10.Text = "Copied and encrypted \"" + Path.GetFileName(inputFilePath) + "\"";
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create subdirectory and write the encrypted files there.

```
string inputDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(inputFilePath);
string outputDir = Path.Combine(inputDir, "EncryptedFiles");
Directory.CreateDirectory(outputDir);

string outputFileName = Path.GetFileName(inputFilePath) + ".AEncrypt";

string outputFilePath = Path.Combine(outputDir, outputFileName);
```

Here I extract directory name from `inputFilePath` and append `"EncryptedFiles"` to it. Then I create your new file name and append it to the generated directory.

`Directory.CreateDirectory()` will create directory if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!